# Web.config Authorization - Allow Security Group

Tags: wcf, iis, web-config

I have the following in my Web.config file, however this does not seem to work with an AD group.

```
 <authorization>
        <allow users="Domain\sg-name" />
        <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
```

When I specify it like this then this works.

```
 <authorization>
        <allow users="Domain\UserName" />
        <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
```

Can I allow an SG or does it have to be a specific user?

When I try

```
 <authorization>
        <allow roles="Domain\sg-name" />
        <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
```

I get this error:
The serviceUri configuration setting was not found.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <authorization>
     <allow roles="Domain\sg-name" />
     <deny users="*" />
 </authorization>
```

There seems to be nothing wrong with this authorization setup. You can set authorization in web.config to allow AD group. [This blog](http://spencerooni.github.io/2015/07/12/authenticating-and-authorizing-users-from-active-directory-in-asp.net.html) details how to authorize users from Active Directory.

> I get this error: The serviceUri configuration setting was not found.

This error message means that there is a problem with your application "serviceUri" configuration, it probably has nothing to do with the authorization configuration itself. You should check your application's configuration file to make sure the "serviceUri" setting exists and is correct.